# Debugging Django Admin Template Resolution

Tags: django-admin, django-templates

Can someone point me to the code or a way that I can say print to screen which admin template is being used?

It happens many a time when I am replacing a admin template for an model that I add the template and hit the page and bham... still the same template.

Usually its a case issue or something like that... but it takes me a while if I get stumped to realise what my issue is.

Can anyone suggest an approach, be it put print statements in django code to show which template is getting resolved?

Regards

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [django-debug-toolbar](http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar), it has a tab that shows all the template_s_ (plural) that are used.

Answer (score 1):

If you run Django's development server from the command line, you can definitely just use print statements to find out which template is being used. You can also use the FireBug plugin for Firefox to figure out what the server is sending back to you.